# Gradle UncheckedIOException

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

My Android Studio project worked correctly, after restart project i got this error :

> Caused by: org.gradle.api.UncheckedIOException: Failed to create directory 'C:\Users\Win\ .gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\32579628dbe4361d42479786c21faaed'

I did these things and the problem is not resolved:

1. `Invalidate caches / restart`
2. `Clean / Rebuild`

Extra info:

Android studio version: `3.4.1`

```
compileSdkVersion: 29
minSdkVersion 21
targetSdkVersion 29
```

Anyone can resolve this problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to path `C:\Users\Win\ .gradle\caches` and manually delete this directory. Note that `.gradle` is a hidden folder.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried the solution **removing the .gradle/caches folder**, but it not worked.
I've tried the solution **Invalidates caches / restart -> rebuild**, but it not worked too.
I solved this updating my gradle version to gradle-6.3 at gradle-wrapper.properties:

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.3-all.zip
```

This gradle version requires Android gradle plugin at least 3.6.0:

```
buildscript {
   dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:$gradle_version"
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, nothing of the above suggested fixes worked.
Eventually, it was a folder permissions setting on Windows' side.